# Get value between given

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need to get all users-ids without *user* prefix, so i trying to get it between dot and end of word.

```
$string = 'users.user_id1, users.user_id2, users.user_id3, users.user_id4';
preg_match_all('/\.(.*?)\/B/', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: he needs actually the $string withouth the user prefix...

Comment: @F.Muller please go through http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: -1 it is hard to tell what you want. An array of user ids, a newly formatted string. Try adding an example of the output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\.)[^,]+(?=,|$)/', $string, $matches);
```

But if you the prefix is fixed, you could use string replace function for the needs.

Comment: Yes, i also thought about that i forget to write about it only now.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$string = 'users.user_id1, users.user_id2, users.user_id3, users.user_id4';
preg_match_all('/users.([^,]+),?/', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: mm, can please update - i need user_id1, user_id2, user_id3, user_id4

Answer (score 1):

```
str_ireplace('users.','',str_ireplace(' ','',$string))
```

It will take care of spaces too
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$string = 'users.user_id1, users.user_id2, users.user_id3, users.user_id4';
$temparray1 = explode(", ", $string);
$temparray2 = array();
foreach ($temparray1 as $value) {
$temp = explode(".", $value);
$temparray2[] = $temp[1];
}
$finalstring = implode(", ", $temparray2);
unset($temparray2);
unset($temparray1);
```

`$finalstring` is the content. It should be: `user_id1, user_id2, user_id3, user_id4`.

Tell me if you need it in another format.

**UPDATE:** Str_replace is also a possibility. Write:

```
$string = 'users.user_id1, users.user_id2, users.user_id3, users.user_id4';
$finalstring = str_replace('users.', '', $string);
```

Just isn't very versatile with the contents of the string.